# dialog image not displaying in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

So I have this little chunkin my function,

```
$("#confirmLink").html("question?").dialog({
    title: "questiontitle?",
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function () {
            $("#confirmLink").html("<div style='margin:auto;'><img style='align:middle;display: block;' src='../images/loading.gif' /> text</div>");
            __doPostBack("button", "1");
        },
        "No": function () {
            $("#confirmLink").html("<div style='margin:auto;'><img style='align:middle;display: block;' src='../images/loading.gif' /> text</div>");
            __doPostBack("button", "0");
        }
    }
});
```

My intention is to replace the question text with the loading.gif. The images folder is in the same location as the page that I am on. This is displaying in IE but not in chrome. Yes, my adblock is turned off.

Comment: I feel that the only person in a position to diagnose this problem is you. I can't see anything wrong with that code (per se) if it's not working it must be some other variable. The fact that it works in IE but not in Chrome makes me think it's a CSS issue but without all the information I can't see how to answer this (vote to close)

Comment: @Liam its the other way around, it works in IE and not chrome.

Comment: That's irrelevant really(amended comment nevertheless)

Comment: "The images folder is in the same location as the page that I am on" - if this is the case the path to the image should be `images/loading.gif` or `./images/loading.gif`